# Formula for Outputting New Row for Each Non-Empty Cell in Specific Range

Tags: google-sheets

I have a range of data which I need to filter by non-empty cells within a specific sub-range, while generating a new row for each non-empty cell within that sub-range.

Observe the following example sheet, containing input data and *desired output*:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c1lOtXpGbY9MwYHEoFIe1fxgW7TnygcgImCIIp2gzqM/edit?usp=sharing

For each "Type 1 - 4" cell that is *not blank*, a new row should be output containing the date, name, type and value from the *input* row.

What formula or functions are needed in order to accomplish this?

I am not new to using `QUERY`, `VLOOKUP`, and `FILTER`, and yet am unable to achieve the desired output via formula, nor even come up with anything that begins to get close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Date", "Name", "Type", "Value"; QUERY({
 QUERY({B3:I, IF(F3:F<>"", $F$2, )},
 "select Col1, Col2, Col9, Col5 where Col9 is not null", 0);
 QUERY({B3:I, IF(G3:G<>"", $G$2, )},
 "select Col1, Col2, Col9, Col6 where Col9 is not null", 0);
 QUERY({B3:I, IF(H3:H<>"", $H$2, )},
 "select Col1, Col2, Col9, Col7 where Col9 is not null", 0);
 QUERY({B3:I, IF(I3:I<>"", $I$2, )},
 "select Col1, Col2, Col9, Col8 where Col9 is not null", 0)},
 "select * order by Col1 asc", 0)})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An alternative answer, similar to player0's in concept, but a bit simpler. It `selects` columns after the full array of ranges has been formed:

```
=arrayformula( 
  query( 
    { 
      B2:B, C2:C, iferror(F2:F/0, F2), F2:F; 
      B2:B, C2:C, iferror(G2:G/0, G2), G2:G; 
      B2:B, C2:C, iferror(H2:H/0, H2), H2:H; 
      B2:B, C2:C, iferror(I2:I/0, I2), I2:I 
    }, 
    "where Col4 is not null 
     order by Col1", 
    0 
  ) 
)
```

Via [Google Product Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/ltdik_L2Sdg;context-place=forum/docs).